# Which app icon should i use?

Tags: icon

My app allows the user to choose a color from a color picker or from an image, and has a wooden background (the one seen in these mockups) throughout. I have these 6 icon mockups, and i'd like your opinion on which one to use?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN5UB.jpg

Comment: I like the bottom-most one as it's showing a complex concept, but visually, at small sizes, it's simple. All that said, heads up that this question will likely be closed as opinion based questions don't really fit on StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

The last in your set stands out as being well balanced and neither completely static nor bland. The landscape colors in the pixelated image fragment on the left, combined with the target in the lower right, immediately make me think of a first-person shooter, though, and I can't shake the impression. A flower, or something else that doesn't say "scenery," would be less ambiguous.

Comment: Aye, I'd go for the last one too. @AlanGilbertson, seems you played a bit of Doom back in the day? :P